# webextension: send confidential data through runtime messages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a webextension which connects to an online database (firebase).
The login process is handled in the popup, currently this gives me a username and password (raw text).

In the contentscript, I need to communicate with the database. To do this, the database handle needs to be authenticated.

Currently, I'm planning to send the credentials from my popup to the background script and to use that to distribute login credentials to the contentscripts.

This would be done via [`browser.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage) and [`tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/sendMessage). Is that a bad idea ? The docs don't talk about their security.

Comment: Excluding the obvious ability of the user to debug your extension and inspect everything, those methods are secure in the sense that only your extension can see the message.